# Error: The getter 'cursorColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error each time I try to run my flutter application. it just throw the error below and the compiler exits.

```
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nb_utils-3.3.0+13/lib/src/AppTextField.dart:181:60: Error: The getter 'cursorColor'     
isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart'
 ('/C:/flutter%20sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'cursorColor'.
      cursorColor: widget.cursorColor ?? Theme.of(context).cursorColor,
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I cannot see any errors. I have already tried running flutter doctor no issues displayed. I am using flutter 3.1.0.
I have also already run 'flutter pub upgrade' and 'flutter pub upgrade --major versions' but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using old version of flutter.

You can do  `flutter upgrade` or `flutter upgrade --force`

The current version of flutter is `3.3.1`
`Theme.of(context).cursorColor` has been replaced with

```dart
Theme.of(context).textSelectionTheme.cursorColor,
```

Comment: I have tried upgrading  flutter to the latest version but it is still throwing the same error

Comment: After running `flutter --version` do you find `Flutter 3.3.x•`?

Comment: Yeah, it is Flutter 3.3.0...

Comment: Can you try reinstalling the flutter sdk

Comment: That still did not work I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `package.lock` file, it seems like it has cached old builds there. Then run `flutter pub get` again after you upgrade your flutter.